# Elasticsearch: sort by field with custom_null values last

Tags: elasticsearch, null

Is there any way in Java to sort by field with custom_null and display it last? Seems that
missing: "_last" doesn't work for custom_null.

Mapping of my property:

```
"myProperty": {
        "type": "keyword",
        "null_value": "NULL"
      }
```

Request in ES:

```
{
"sort" : [
    { "myProperty" :  {"missing" : "_last"}}
] }
```

Results:

1. myProperty = A
2. myProperty = B
3. myProperty = null
4. myProperty = W

Comment: could you please add an example query

Comment: I added into my question

Answer (score 0):

I created script for that:

```
{

"query": {
    "function_score": {
        "boost_mode": "replace",
        "query": {"match_all": {}},
        "script_score": {
            "script": "doc['myProperty'].value == 'NULL' ? 0 : 1"
        }   
    }
},
"sort": [
   "_score",
   {"myProperty": "desc"}
]}
```